# Android List view with clickable button

Tags: android, listview, adapter

Hi guys I am implementing a listview with a clickable button through this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEEYYvVwJGY
and I want to achieve the same output.
But I have a slight problem, since my list view is populated from mysql database but in the tutorial is not populated from mysql database so we have a different adapter.

Codes in the tutorial

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{

private ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, data));
}

}
```

Then lets assume that this is the tutorials MyListAdapter

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
    private int layout;
    public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        layout = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
        if (convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
            convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
            ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.tvid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studId);
            viewHolder.tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studName);
            viewHolder.btnP = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.present);
            viewHolder.btnA = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.absent);
            viewHolder.btnP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Button Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        }
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

and my problem is in this part 
the setAdapter

```
 mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Attendance.this,
                        studentList, R.layout.list_att, new String[]{
                        TAG_ID, TAG_NAME}, new int[]{
                       R.id.studId, R.id.studName});
                mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

what should I do? any help would be appreciated thanks in advance :)

this is my code

```
public class Attendance extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView Date;;
    ListView mylistView;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    TextView Name;

    private static String url = "http://10.0.2.2/MobileClassRecord/getStudent.php";

    private static final  String TAG_STUDENTS = "students";
    private static final  String TAG_ID = "stud_id";
    private static final  String TAG_NAME = "stud_name";

    JSONArray students = null;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_attendance);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        Date = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        int dd = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        int mm = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int yy = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);

        Date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(yy).append("-").append(mm + 1).append("-").append(dd));

        new JSONParse().execute();

        studentList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }

    private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask<String, String, JSONObject>{
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            Name =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.studName);
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Attendance.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Getting Data from Database...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();

        }

        @Override
        protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) {
            JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

            JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);
            return json;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                students = jsonObject.getJSONArray(TAG_STUDENTS);
                for (int i = 0; i < students.length(); i++){
                    JSONObject c =students.getJSONObject(i);

                    final String Id = c.getString(TAG_ID);
                    String Name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);

                    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                    map.put(TAG_ID, Id);
                    map.put(TAG_NAME, Name);

                    studentList.add(map);
                    mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
                    final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(Attendance.this,
                            studentList, R.layout.list_att, new String[]{
                            TAG_ID, TAG_NAME}, new int[]{
                           R.id.studId, R.id.studName});
                    mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
                    mylistView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                            String ID = ((TextView) (view.findViewById(R.id.studId))).getText().toString();
                            Toast.makeText(Attendance.this, "List Clicked " + ID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MyApp", MODE_PRIVATE);
                            preferences.edit().putString("id", ID).commit();
                        }
                    });

                }
            }catch (JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private class MyListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{
        private int layout;
        public MyListAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<String> objects) {
            super(context, resource, objects);
            layout = resource;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
            if (convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
                convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
                ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
                viewHolder.tvid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studId);
                viewHolder.tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studName);
                viewHolder.btnP = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.present);
                viewHolder.btnA = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.absent);
                viewHolder.btnP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Button Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
                convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
            }
            mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            mainViewHolder.tvid.setText(getItem(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        TextView tvid, tvname;
        Button btnP, btnA;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_attendance, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case android.R.id.home:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Attendance.this, SpecificClassRecord.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                return true;
            case R.id.action_view_attendance:
                Intent intent1 = new Intent(Attendance.this, ViewAttendance.class);
                startActivity(intent1);
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

[Sample Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STnBc.png)

Comment: What is your datasource? and I think you should be more clear of where is the problem you have, because I don't think users will watch the 17 minutes video you've attached.

Comment: `final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter` you are not using your adapter

Comment: `"Getting Data from Database..."` you are not accessing a database either (at least not in a relevant way)

Answer (score 0):

like Udi said, more information would be nice.

One strange thing in your code is in the getView() method.

you have

```
if(convertView==null){
  ...
}else{
...
}
```

I think the else part is wrong. Just remove the else and the brackets (not the code insight of it).
The code in the else part is important, because without it the code will not change the TextView when the View is loaded for the first time. This mean, that your getView will do nothing

EDIT

The author has changed the code. You have now two different adapters there...

In my opinion the getView() Method should look like this

```
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder mainViewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        convertView = inflater.inflate(layout, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvid = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studId);
        viewHolder.tvname = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studName);
        viewHolder.btnP = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.present);
        viewHolder.btnA = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.absent);
        viewHolder.btnP.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Button Clicked " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    }
    mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    mainViewHolder.tvid.setText(getItem(position));
    return convertView;
}
}
```

But for me it is still not clear where exactly the problem is. Is the App crashing or is there just a behavior you don't understand? If yes, what exactly?
If the App is crashing, when exactly?

EDIT 2:

```
mylistView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
            final ListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(Attendance.this,
                     R.layout.list_att, new String[]{
                    TAG_ID, TAG_NAME});
            mylistView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

maybe this is all. I assume the layout of your rows is given by the layoutressource R.layout.list_att and that TAG_ID and TAG_Name are defined somewhere before.

I see your new Adapter needs a List of Strings. Insert the following before you set the adapter

```
List<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();
test.add("1");
test.add("2"):
test.add("3");
```

and then your adapter should look like this

```
final ListAdapter adapter = new MyListAdapter(Attendance.this,
                     R.layout.list_att, test);
```

Comment: I don't think the else fork is wrong. But `mainViewHolder.tvid.setText(getItem(position));` in the else fork might be wrong.

Comment: depends on what he wants to do.. In his code he will leave the textview empty when the view is loaded for the first time. When he scrolls a little bit and the view has to be updated, the textview will show something. I don't believe that this is the behavior he wants to have

Comment: True. I misread his code. Now I see that he was creating a second `ViewHolder` called `viewHolder`. Don't know, why he is not using his `mainViewHolder`. Then he could leave `mainViewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();` in the else fork.

Comment: @StephanHuewe hi sir it is not crashing maybe there is something I cant understand. In the tutorials code that i've attach it has this line of code lv.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, data)); 
but in my case it is only like this mylistView.setAdapter(adapter); and it is inside the private class JSONParse extends AsyncTask and i know that i cant add a getView in the AsyncTask. so what I am asking is a remedy between the adapters as you can see above my adapter is ListAdapter and the other one isa like a customAdapter which is MyListAdapter.

Comment: there should be no problem. You can access the User Interface from onPostExcecute(). Like njzk mentions, you don't use your own Adapter. You use new SimpleAdapter instead of new MyListAdapter

Comment: @StephanHuewe hi sir the default or original adapter that i have use in populating the listview is the simple adapter. and since i am aiming to implement a listview with a button i found the tutorial and then here comes the MyListAdapter and getView.

Comment: @StephanHuewe hi sir i don't think i need a list of string because I'm accessing the data in mysql database. I added my whole code and attach the sample layout, please see it one more time sir i really need to implement this.